# How to print the values of objects stored in a list

Tags: python

I'm trying to iterate over `User` objects stored in a python list called `myusers` then print each. This is what I've done:

```
class User:
    def __init__(self,name,age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

myusers= [User("Fred", "30"), User("Doe", "20")] 

for i in range(2):
    print(str(myusers[i]))
```

what I get from the above is the memory location as follows:

```
<__main__.User object at 0x000001FD807B4250>
<__main__.User object at 0x000001FD807F13A0>
```

However, I was expecting to get:

```
User("Fred", "30")
User("Doe", "20")
```

I've seen this question: `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59115308/print-out-objects-stored-in-a-list` but it didn't answer my question since I'm using str in the print function. Can anyone let me know when I'm not getting this value?

Comment: you would need to write a `__str__` function in your class, so your class knows how to turn its self into a string.

Comment: The accepted answer in that question _does exactly what you need!_

Comment: Also, you don't need to explicitly convert to a string by `str()` before printing. `print()` already does that for you if the argument isn't a string.

Answer (score 1):

As remarked in the comments, you should define a `__str__` method, which defines how to represent your object as a string.

```
class User:
    def __init__(self,name,age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
    def __str__(self):
        return f'User("{self.name}", "{self.age}")'

myusers= [User("Fred", "30"), User("Doe", "20")] 

for i in range(2):
    print(myusers[i])
```